# Downgrade SDK 23 to 22 issues

Tags: android, sdk, android-gradle-plugin, android-manifest

I was using **SDK 23** but the system of permissions make me come back to the **SDK 22**, but I'm facing a problem that is quite common here. I visited every link but no one could really help me.
The error that I'm facing is this one:

[image: error]

I have my manifest like this:

[image: manifest]

And my gradle file is like this:

[image: gradle]

[image: gradle2]

```
dependencies {
compile files('ormlite-android-4.49-SNAPSHOT.jar')
compile files('ormlite-core-4.49-SNAPSHOT.jar')
compile files('ormlite-jdbc-4.49-SNAPSHOT.jar')
compile files('signalr-client-sdk.jar')
compile files('signalr-client-sdk-android.jar')
compile project(':viewPageIndicator')
compile project(':netlogiaChartsLib')
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.1'
compile 'com.github.alamkanak:android-week-view:1.2.6'
```

}

I don't know how but android studio keeps calling the SDK 23, although I already deleted from SDK manager and I only have the 22. Why is it giving this error?

Comment: *Why is it giving this error?* it is obvious, you are using resources which can be found only on API 23 ... obviously deleting whole `values-23` should help

Comment: I will try it @Selvin

Comment: @Selvin, i try it by opening the Theme Editor and change the sdk level to 22 and still got this error. If i delete the content of the **values-v23.xml** it's automatically  genereted, and the error message appear.

Comment: Post your dependencies

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti, i updated the post. Still didn't get to work on sdk 22 and thank you for commenting!

Comment: Did you try to use gradle clean before assembling again?

Comment: I did the "clean project" and "rebuild" and still got the problem to "Button.Inverse" and "Button.Colored".

Comment: Have someone found issue on it..am also getting same problem